# How to edit Salesforce CPQ quote line editor fields

Tags: cpq, quote, quotelineitem

I am trying to update the unit price on the salesforce CPQ quote line editor to say fixed price but for some reasons I cannot access it. Every topic and video I've seen points to field sets but it's not under field sets. I have attached images for guidance if anyone has an idea where to make this change. I also tried 3rd party tools like workbench to access that field and update the name but the tool is unable to pull that field label. [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is in the field sets of the Product Option object, and once edited/added:

- you can add the api name of the field set in the picklist (SBQQ__ConfigurationFieldSet__c) of the wanted object (feature/product..)
  And the last step, choose the field set you want in that picklist(data part):
- SBQQ__ConfigurationFieldSet__c(SBQQ__ProductFeature__c)
- SBQQ__ConfigurationFieldSet__c(Product2)...